# How to bind an array to an HTML tag in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Below is a snip of my powershell code where my response or my variable($witrevisions) is of type array. I am looking to bind this in a html tag which i have defined in the power shell. As I am very new to coding stuff , I am looking the ways how can I bind array to html tag in best possible way

...continuing my line of code

```
$response4s = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader).values
$wits = $response4s | where({$_.fields.'System.WorkItemType' -eq 'Task'}) # Only retrieve Tasks
$witrevisions = @()
foreach($wit in $response4s){
    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
      "Title" = $wit.fields.'System.Title'
      "AssignedTo" = $wit.fields.'System.AssignedTo'
 } 

    $witrevisions += $customObject      
             }
    $witrevisions | Select-Object `
              Title,                                         
              AssignedTo
}
```

and this the sample response i am getting in $witrevisions which i have exported in text file. its a table with two column one having emails and other having a title name.i have tried to show by giving it a table view for better understanding

```
 Assigned To                   Title
xyz@outlook.com                testingpro
drdr@outlook.com               resttesting
```

and here is the html tag where I trying to bind the $witrevisions.

```
$DOWNLOAD_PAGE_BODY_CONTENT = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    `n<html>
    `n<head>
    `n  <title>Validation</title>    
    `n</head>
    `n<body>
    `n
    `n<p>Please click the <a href=" + $($uploadResponse.webUrl) + ">link</a> to download the release.</p>
    `n<p></p>
    `n<p></p>
    `n<p>$witrevisions</p>
    `n</body>
    `n</html>
    `n"
```

Can someone please tell me how should I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of some code that would take your array and emit a table, with an explanation to help you tweak to your specific needs:

```
"<table><body>$($witrevisions|% {"<tr><td>$($_.Title)</td><td>$($_.AssignedTo)</td></tr>"} )</body></table>"
```

The double quotes are important because they allow string interpolation (it will replace variables with this value, versus being read a plain text.  E.g. `'[' + $test +  ']'`  => `"[$test]"`

If you need to do more complex logic in string interpolation, you can use `$(...)`, the ellipses being regular code.

You can iterate through an array by piping to the `ForEach-Object`, or it's alias `%`. All the  code in the braces will be executed for each item in the array.  The current items is represented by `$_`.

We're then back to string interpolation and using `$(...)`, which is needed to access the members of the current item.

---

Note: There are several other ways to accomplish (functionally) the same thing.  E.g. `foreach(...){}` vs `|%{...}`, so feel free to use a different technique if you are more comfortable with doing something a different way.